# Javascript save content from web telegram Chrome window to text file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I login and I open web.telegram.org. Here I open Chrome developer tools and I need to auto save messages at certain intervals of time. For saving the content of a div to a file I have used the following.

```
divs = document.getElementsByClassName('im_message_text'); 
var count = divs; 
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('im_message_text')[count.length-1]; 
console.save(x.innerText);
```

How can I make this automatically save every one second into a specified folder with customized file name?

Thanks!

Comment: yuo can use [my download script](https://github.com/rndme/download/) to save named files from client-side code. If you do multiples, you'll have to agree to a browser click-through after the 2nd or 3rd one. You also need to change the download prefs from the default folder to a specific location.

Comment: It is working but how can I put automatically run from second to second?

Comment: wrap your code in a function, call `setInterval` on that function. google `setInterval` for details